# SPI.hとSD.hをインクルード時のコンパイルエラー: "複数のライブラリが見つかりました"

Tags: spresense

SPI.hとSD.hをインクルードした際に "複数のライブラリが見つかりました" と表示され、コンパイルエラーになってしまいます。開発環境はArduinoIDEです。

**表示されたエラーメッセージ**

「SPI.h」に対して複数のライブラリが見つかりました 使用済：C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SPRESENSE\hardware\spresense\1.4.2\libraries\SPI 
「SD.h」に対して複数のライブラリが見つかりました 使用済：C:\Program 次のフォルダのライブラリSPIバージョン1.2.0を使用中：C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SPRESENSE\hardware\spresense\1.4.2\libraries\SPI 次のフォルダのライブラリSDバージョン1.2.3を使用中：C:\Program Files exit status 1 ボードSpresenseに対するコンパイル時にエラーが発生しました。

Comment: エラーメッセージはとても重要です。自分勝手に翻訳せずありのままのエラーメッセージをコピペするよう編集してみてください。

Comment: 質問は後からでも編集できるので、本文に追記してみて下さい。質問が編集されると一覧のトップに上がるので、回答してくれるかもしれない人の目に留まりやすくなります。

Answer (score 1):

SPRESENSEボード上のSDカードを使用する場合は、
SD.hの代わりにSDHCI.hをincludeして、次のように使います。

```
#include <SDHCI.h>
SDClass SD;
```

マニュアル：[SDHCIライブラリ](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_sdhci_library) や
SDカードを使う色々なexamplesが揃っているのでそれらが参考になると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にさせて頂きます。